# Remove unwanted whitespace with GridSpec

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a complex figure layout using matplotlib and GridSpec. Several of the panels have colorbars and to make sure they're aligned I'm placing them in adjacent subplots created with GridSpec. However, when I do this and use GridSpec's tight_layout I get extra whitespace which I can't figure out how to eliminate. Here's a distilled version of what I'm doing.

```
from matplotlib import gridspec

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8.5,11))

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 4, width_ratios=[.48,.02,.48,.02],wspace=0,hspace=0)

for i in [0,1]:
    for j in [0,2]:
        d = np.random.random((200,200))
        ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[i,j])
        ax_cb = fig.add_subplot(gs[i,j+1])
        sns.heatmap(d,cmap='jet',ax=ax, cbar_ax=ax_cb)

gs.tight_layout(fig)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZdcd.png)

I'm guessing there's some kind of artist left behind by the colorbar maybe? But I can't figure out how to get rid of it.

Comment: The output image looks pretty much expected. There should be similar questions with almost the exact same title showing how to remove whitespace with a GridSpec. They might not cover colorbars, in which case it would still be useful to show how far you can get with the answers in your case.